# Old, space-themed comic from the '90s or earlier, involving a female character with cat ears and a tail

Tags: story-identification, comics, space

I remember one of the female characters had cat ears and a tail; I think she was involved with another character romantically. In fact, I think there was some nudity and it might have had a softcore sex scene. There was another female who was much taller, I think with white hair and maybe a green jumpsuit?

I read this comic in the '90s, but found it in a discount bin, so maybe it came out before then. It was a single issue comic; I think it *might* have had 'Star' in the title. If I can remember more about it, I'll add to this.

Comment: Urgh. I just pulled off the bookcase a possible candidate last week and cannot remember the name. I'll try to dig it out again. It's not Marvel's Starjammers, is it?

Comment: I don't think it's fits but I was thinking of [Swords of the Swashbucklers](https://www.comicon.com/2017/05/03/guice-and-mantlos-swords-of-the-swashbucklers-is-currently-funding-a-new-edition/) by Bill Mantlo and Jackson Guice.

Comment: Maybe Dreadstar?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreadstar

Comment: Sadly I don't think it's Starjammers or Dreadstar. I'm worried I might be wrong about Star being in the title.

Comment: I know this is totally unlikely to be the answer, but in the 70s Hanna-Barbera cartoon show "Josie and Pussycats in Outer Space", the titular Josie and her all girl band the Pussycats had cat themed costumes complete with ears and tails.

Comment: I suspect that many stories involving felinoids were partly inspired by [The Ballad of Lost C'Mell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ballad_of_Lost_C%27Mell).

Comment: @NomadMaker: Not Dreadstar - the only recurring feline character is a guy and has no tail.

Answer (score 9):

WOW I JUST FOUND IT! Stumbled upon Comic Vine searching for characters. Set tags to female and alien and just went through till I recognized one. The comic is ***[Sun Devils](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Sun_Devils_Vol_1)*** (1984-1985).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Devils_(comics)):

> *Sun Devils* is a science fiction "space opera" comic book series published by DC Comics for 12 issues between July 1984 and June 1985. Writers Gerry Conway, Roy Thomas and artist Dan Jurgens created the series.

The woman with the tail (no cat ears) is [Anomie Zitar](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Anomie_Zitar_(Sun_Devils)), and the taller woman is [Scyla](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Scyla_(Sun_Devils)). Can't believe I finally found this after 25+ years!

Thanks for the help everyone. :) [Issue #3](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Sun_Devils_Vol_1_3) (September, 1984) was the comic I owned and referenced.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: Well, first they would have to [merge their accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

Belgian comic book artist Jean Torton, alias Jeronaton made an album that in my home country was issued back in 1980, *[Kvinnan från stjärnorna](https://libris.kb.se/bib/7404232)*. The title translates into English "Woman from the Stars". I'm unsure about when and how it was printed in English, but French-Belgian comics, *bandes dessinées*, are generally quite popular worldwide.

Here's the cover. The titular main character is a feline humanoid and there's nudity:

> [image: Image of a topless feline woman]